# Displaying google maps within nested divs (splitter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I've read many answers to the issue of map not being displayed when put inside nested divs, i tried everything but still could not get it working.
I need to have a splitter between directions panel and the actual map, and i am using the code i've found for splitter, combined with the map code. But map is never displayed, only grey background.
I have to admit i am illiterate with HTML design, CSS and JavaScript. Please if anyone could easily see the issue, i would be very grateful. Thank you.

```
   <HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en&libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyASrsCWlCQ1YlOlkgyf3tMQf8EiOU8rKv0"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
   <style>

    html, body, {
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           height: 500px;
           width: 500px;
       }

   .simple {
       height: 1000px;
       width: 1000px;
       position: absolute
   }

   .simple div {
       overflow: auto
   }

   .hsplitbar {
       height: 5px;
       background: #cab
   }

   .hsplitbar:hover{
       background: #eab
   }
   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">


    ;(function($){

    $.fn.splitter = function(args){
           args = args || {};
           return this.each(function() {
                   var zombie;             // left-behind splitbar for outline resizes
                   function startSplitMouse(evt) {
                           if ( opts.outline )
                                   zombie = zombie || bar.clone(false).insertAfter(A);
                           panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "none");       // Safari selects A/B text on a move
                           bar.addClass(opts.activeClass);
                           A._posSplit = A[0][opts.pxSplit] - evt[opts.eventPos];
                           $(document)
                                   .bind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
                                   .bind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
                   }
                   function doSplitMouse(evt) {
                           var newPos = A._posSplit+evt[opts.eventPos];
                           if ( opts.outline ) {
                                   newPos = Math.max(0, Math.min(newPos, splitter._DA - bar._DA));
                                   bar.css(opts.origin, newPos);
                           } else 
                                   resplit(newPos);
                   }
                   function endSplitMouse(evt) {
                           bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass);
                           var newPos = A._posSplit+evt[opts.eventPos];
                           if ( opts.outline ) {
                                   zombie.remove(); zombie = null;
                                   resplit(newPos);
                           }
                           panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "text");       // let Safari select text again
                           $(document)
                                   .unbind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
                                   .unbind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
                          }

                   function resplit(newPos) {
                           // Constrain new splitbar position to fit pane size limits
                           newPos = Math.max(A._min, splitter._DA - B._max, 
                                           Math.min(newPos, A._max, splitter._DA - bar._DA - B._min));
                           // Resize/position the two panes
                           bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];         // bar size may change during dock
                           bar.css(opts.origin, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                           A.css(opts.origin, 0).css(opts.split, newPos).css(opts.fixed,  splitter._DF);
                           B.css(opts.origin, newPos+bar._DA)
                                   .css(opts.split, splitter._DA-bar._DA-newPos).css(opts.fixed,  splitter._DF);
                           // IE fires resize for us; all others pay cash
                           if ( !$.browser.msie )
                                   panes.trigger("resize");
                   }
                   function dimSum(jq, dims) {
                           // Opera returns -1 for missing min/max width, turn into 0
                           var sum = 0;
                           for ( var i=1; i < arguments.length; i++ )
                                   sum += Math.max(parseInt(jq.css(arguments[i])) || 0, 0);
                           return sum;
                   }

                   // Determine settings based on incoming opts, element classes, and defaults
                   var vh = (args.splitHorizontal? 'h' : args.splitVertical? 'v' : args.type) || 'v';
                   var opts = $.extend({
                           activeClass: 'active',  // class name for active splitter
                           pxPerKey: 8,                    // splitter px moved per keypress
                           tabIndex: 0,                    // tab order indicator
                           accessKey: ''                   // accessKey for splitbar
                   },{
                           v: {                                    // Vertical splitters:
                                   keyLeft: 39, keyRight: 37, cursor: "e-resize",
                                   splitbarClass: "vsplitbar", outlineClass: "voutline",
                                   type: 'v', eventPos: "pageX", origin: "left",
                                   split: "width",  pxSplit: "offsetWidth",  side1: "Left", side2: "Right",
                                   fixed: "height", pxFixed: "offsetHeight", side3: "Top",  side4: "Bottom"
                           },
                           h: {                                    // Horizontal splitters:
                                   keyTop: 40, keyBottom: 38,  cursor: "n-resize",
                                   splitbarClass: "hsplitbar", outlineClass: "houtline",
                                   type: 'h', eventPos: "pageY", origin: "top",
                                   split: "height", pxSplit: "offsetHeight", side1: "Top",  side2: "Bottom",
                                   fixed: "width",  pxFixed: "offsetWidth",  side3: "Left", side4: "Right"
                           }
                   }[vh], args);

                   // Create jQuery object closures for splitter and both panes
                   var splitter = $(this).css({position: "relative"});
                   var panes = $(">*", splitter[0]).css({
                           position: "absolute",                   // positioned inside splitter container
                           "z-index": "1",                                 // splitbar is positioned above
                           "-moz-outline-style": "none"    // don't show dotted outline
                   });
                   var A = $(panes[0]);            // left  or top
                   var B = $(panes[1]);            // right or bottom

                   // Focuser element, provides keyboard support; title is shown by Opera accessKeys
                   var focuser = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>')
                           .attr({accessKey: opts.accessKey, tabIndex: opts.tabIndex, title: opts.splitbarClass})
                           .bind($.browser.opera?"click":"focus", function(){ this.focus(); bar.addClass(opts.activeClass) })
                           .bind("keydown", function(e){
                                   var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
                                   var dir = key==opts["key"+opts.side1]? 1 : key==opts["key"+opts.side2]? -1 : 0;
                                   if ( dir )
                                           resplit(A[0][opts.pxSplit]+dir*opts.pxPerKey, false);
                           })
                           .bind("blur", function(){ bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass) });

                   // Splitbar element, can be already in the doc or we create one
                   var bar = $(panes[2] || '<div></div>')
                           .insertAfter(A).css("z-index", "100").append(focuser)
                           .attr({"class": opts.splitbarClass, unselectable: "on"})
                           .css({position: "absolute",     "user-select": "none", "-webkit-user-select": "none",
                                   "-khtml-user-select": "none", "-moz-user-select": "none"})
                           .bind("mousedown", startSplitMouse);
                   // Use our cursor unless the style specifies a non-default cursor
                   if ( /^(auto|default|)$/.test(bar.css("cursor")) )
                           bar.css("cursor", opts.cursor);

                   // Cache several dimensions for speed, rather than re-querying constantly
                   bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];
                   splitter._PBF = $.boxModel? dimSum(splitter, "border"+opts.side3+"Width", "border"+opts.side4+"Width") : 0;
                   splitter._PBA = $.boxModel? dimSum(splitter, "border"+opts.side1+"Width", "border"+opts.side2+"Width") : 0;
                   A._pane = opts.side1;
                   B._pane = opts.side2;
                   $.each([A,B], function(){
                           this._min = opts["min"+this._pane] || dimSum(this, "min-"+opts.split);
                           this._max = opts["max"+this._pane] || dimSum(this, "max-"+opts.split) || 9999;
                           this._init = opts["size"+this._pane]===true ?
                                   parseInt($.curCSS(this[0],opts.split)) : opts["size"+this._pane];
                   });

                   // Determine initial position, get from cookie if specified
                   var initPos = A._init;
                   if ( !isNaN(B._init) )  // recalc initial B size as an offset from the top or left side
                           initPos = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - B._init - bar._DA;
                   if ( opts.cookie ) {
                           if ( !$.cookie )
                                   alert('jQuery.splitter(): jQuery cookie plugin required');
                           var ckpos = parseInt($.cookie(opts.cookie));
                           if ( !isNaN(ckpos) )
                                   initPos = ckpos;
                           $(window).bind("unload", function(){
                                   var state = String(bar.css(opts.origin));       // current location of splitbar
                                   $.cookie(opts.cookie, state, {expires: opts.cookieExpires || 365, 
                                           path: opts.cookiePath || document.location.pathname});
                           });
                   }
                   if ( isNaN(initPos) )   // King Solomon's algorithm
                           initPos = Math.round((splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - bar._DA)/2);

                   // Resize event propagation and splitter sizing
                   if ( opts.anchorToWindow ) {
                           // Account for margin or border on the splitter container and enforce min height
                           splitter._hadjust = dimSum(splitter, "borderTopWidth", "borderBottomWidth", "marginBottom");
                           splitter._hmin = Math.max(dimSum(splitter, "minHeight"), 20);
                           $(window).bind("resize", function(){
                                   var top = splitter.offset().top;
                                   var wh = $(window).height();
                                   splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh-top-splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin)+"px");
                                   if ( !$.browser.msie ) splitter.trigger("resize");
                           }).trigger("resize");
                   }
                   else if ( opts.resizeToWidth && !$.browser.msie )
                           $(window).bind("resize", function(){
                                   splitter.trigger("resize"); 
                           });

                   // Resize event handler; triggered immediately to set initial position
                   splitter.bind("resize", function(e, size){
                           // Custom events bubble in jQuery 1.3; don't Yo Dawg
                           if ( e.target != this ) return;
                           // Determine new width/height of splitter container
                           splitter._DF = splitter[0][opts.pxFixed] - splitter._PBF;
                           splitter._DA = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA;
                           // Bail if splitter isn't visible or content isn't there yet
                           if ( splitter._DF <= 0 || splitter._DA <= 0 ) return;
                           // Re-divvy the adjustable dimension; maintain size of the preferred pane
                           resplit(!isNaN(size)? size : (!(opts.sizeRight||opts.sizeBottom)? A[0][opts.pxSplit] :
                                   splitter._DA-B[0][opts.pxSplit]-bar._DA));
                   }).trigger("resize" , [initPos]);
           });
    };

    })(jQuery);

     var geocoder;
     var map;
     var startMarker;
     var AllMarkers = [];
     var routeRectangle;

     var drawingManager;
     var directionsService;
     var directionsDisplay;

     var waypts = [];
     var routeWaypts = [];
     var routeMarkers = [];

     var start;
     var finish;

     var route;

     var addresses = [];

     var innerHTML;

     var totalDistance = 0;
     var totalDuration = 0;


     function initialize() {

       $().ready(function() {
         $(".simple").splitter({type: 'h', accessKey: 'M'});
       });

       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

       var myOptions = {
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         panControl: true,
         zoomControl: true,
         mapTypeControl: true,
         scaleControl: true,
         streetViewControl: true,
         overviewMapControl: true
       };

       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

       geocoder.geocode({'address': 'US'}, function (results, status) {
            var ne = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
            var sw = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();

            map.setZoom(20);

            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
       });

   </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="initialize()">
   <div  class="simple">
   <div id="directions_panel" style="500px;height:500px"></div>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="500px;height:500px"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! What does it mean actually?

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
.simple div {
   overflow: auto
}
```

with that:

```
.simple>div {
   overflow: auto
}
```